# Issue when assigning values to Custom Model Binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, custom-binding, custom-model-binder

I am getting

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in *****Tests.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How to correctly assign values to the binding model?

```
public class PersonRegistration
{
    RegisterBindingModel model;
    [TestMethod]
   
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(userManager, loggingService);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
```

I am getting the exception when executing `model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";`

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    public RegisterBindingModel();
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is a need to, you typically don't test controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RegisterBindingModel model` not initialized.

> For this reason unhandled null exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).occurred.

So try something like:

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{   
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonRegistration
{
    RegisterBindingModel model= new RegisterBindingModel ();//initialized
    [TestMethod]

    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(userManager, loggingService);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message is a little cryptic, but it says that something is null that you thought wasn't.

`RegisterBindingModel model;` doesn't have an instance. Give it one and it should work. If it still errors, wrap everything in a try catch and debug it.

`RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();`

Answer (score 0):

You declared a model but you did not initialized it for it to point to some place in memory. Try writting 
RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();